# How to search under condition that field may or may not exist in Elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, exists, elasticsearch-query

I am doing a search in elasticsearch with a must clause. But there is flag field that may or may not be present in elasticsearch. So how do i code this? In below example, field 'c' is uncertain. Its it's present than i must search with it else i can ignore...

```
   "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "match": {
                            "a": "norm"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "match_phrase": {
                            "b": "views"
                        }
                    },
                "must_not": {
                    "exists": {
                        "field": "c"
                    }
                 },
                    {
                        "match_phrase": {
                            "c": "claims"
                        }
                    }
                ]}
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Query is fairly self explanatory. I have added a should clause with a match on field c and no exists check on field c. Minimum_should_match is set as 1. A document which matches either of clause is returned i.e either it should not exist or should match the input string

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "a": "norm"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "b": "views"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "c": "claims"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "c"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

**Data:**

```
 "hits" : [
      {
        "_source" : {
          "a" : "norm",
          "b" : "views",
          "c" : "claims"
        }
      },
      {
        "_source" : {
          "a" : "norm",
          "b" : "views"
        }
      },
      {
        "_source" : {
          "a" : "norm",
          "b" : "views",
          "c" : "ddd"
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Result:**

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_source" : {
          "a" : "norm",
          "b" : "views",
          "c" : "claims"
        }
      },
      {
        "_source" : {
          "a" : "norm",
          "b" : "views"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Document where c="claims" or c not exists is returned

Comment: thanks alot for this solution, but unfortunately its not working out. Its giving me error `elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', '[bool] query does not support [bool]')
`

Comment: @TrickOrTreat It is working at my end. Are you using same query or have done any modification

Comment: i am using this code without modification only.. Just changing the column name to the official data. Rest should work.. but it's throwing error

Comment: @TrickOrTreat Can you add query you are running here . I doubled checked mine is returning result.

Answer (score -1):

Use filter and exist.

[exists](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html)

[filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html)

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": [
            {
              "missing": {
                "field": "your_field"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```